# Flask/Pymongo JSON response to Java

Tags: java, flask, pymongo

I'm retrieving all documents in my mongo collection that match a substring query:

```
cursor = db.users.find({"username": {'$regex': username}})
```

and then returning all of the matching documents as a JSONArray to the java client:

```
jsonArray = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in cursor]
return json.dumps(jsonArray)
```

When I want to parse through the JSONArray on the java side, I have to do the following:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    String s = json.getString(i);
    JSONObject row = new JSONObject(s);
    .....
```

I'm fairly confident that I'm doing something wrong here. I shouldn't have to convert the JSONArray element to a string and then to a JSONObject. Is there anyway that I can directly retrieve the JSONObject from the JSONArray without first converting it to a string?

Comment: can u post the sample json data format you required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a JSON array of strings, not a JSON array of objects.

The `getJSONObject` won't parse the string to return an object.

You have to return a list of objects from your Flask code:

```
return json.dumps(list(cursor), default=json_util.default)
```

After that, use Menno code.

Comment: is
    list(cursor)
the same as
    [doc for doc in cursor]
?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [`JSONArray.getJSONObject(int index)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject%28int%29)?

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = json.getJSONObject(i);
    .....
```

Comment: Yes that is ideally what I want, but that throws an exception for me. It forces me to convert it to a string and then to a JSONObject.

Comment: Can you post the exception and the json file you're trying to read?

Comment: Value {"username": "danny", "phone_number": ".....", "password": "pbkdf2:sha1:1000$huGJOzcP$80b2d59676048a27a6fe2deaf29b1a6a681374a4", "pictures": {}, "created_on": {"$date": 1392862827215}, "_id": {"$oid": "5305666bebc2e5e5cdec37b5"}, "friends": [], "email": "....."} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject